# Why does "wind" have two different pronunciations?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, vowels, phonology

The word "wind" seems to be problematic (with almost all other English words that behave strangely). When it is used as a noun to mean the movement of air, it is pronounced to rhyme with "bit" (the vowel part) but its verb (meaning: move in or take a twisting or spiral course) rhymes with "find".

It appears that they originated from the same word? There are many other words in English that behave like this but I am only interested in this one.

Noun → /w**ɪ**nd/
Verb → /w**aɪ**nd/

Why is it this way?

Comment: Why have you spelled "curious" as "qurious" ;-) because English has a good history.

Comment: According to Oxford dictionaries, the 'weather' one is _Old English, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch 'wind' and German 'Wind', from an Indo-European root shared by Latin 'ventus'_. The verb is from _Old English 'windan' ‘go rapidly’, ‘twine’, of Germanic origin; related to 'wander' and 'wend'_. Incidentally, some old poetry does require 'wind' (weather) to rhyme with 'find'.

Comment: Many if not most Anglophones today distinguish two fundamentally different pronunciations for *These are the toys I **have** to play with*, where enunciating the normal "soft" /v/ (HAV) in ***have*** conveys the sense of *These toys **are available to me** to play with*. But it can also be articulated with a "hard" /f/ (HAFF) to mean *I **must** play with these toys.* In that example, obviously it was originally the same verb ***to have*** - but for at least *some* of us, it's effectively diverged into two completely different sounds and meanings. ***Because English,*** as they say! :)

Comment: There’s more than one noun and one verb “wind”. Compare: “He got winded” (verb of the noun wind you noted, both pronounced the same) and “Let’s give the clock another wind” (noun of the verb wind that you noted, both pronounced the same).

Comment: Based on Kate Bunting's comment, I would say that you have two words with a single spelling, not one word with two pronunciations. But that does not make your question any less interesting.

Comment: You should be asking why the two pronunciations have the same spelling.

Comment: Kate Bunting says that “some old poetry does require ‘wind’ (weather) to rhyme with ‘find’,“ cites Shakespeare & a Carol below. I wonder if either/both of those date from when both *were* pronounced same, only *now* we find it odd. I was just reading Gerard Manley Hopkins “The Lantern Out of Doors” (Hopkins lived 1844-1889) Per letters, GMH OBSESSED w/perfect rhymes @ line ends, so was shocked to see these @ end of last 6 lines: wind, end, mind; amend, kind, friend.. Rhyme scheme MUST be CDC, DCD… unsure if he meant weather or ‘wend’ sense, Hopkins’ meaning  sometimes opaque. Read poem to see?

Comment: https://hopkinspoetry.com/poem/the-lantern-out-of-doors/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## ;

'Wind' (n) and 'wind' (v) had the same vowel in Old English. Both had a short vowel /i/ which was lengthened in Late OE due to a sound change triggered by consonant clusters such as /nd, ld, mb, rd/ etc. The vowel in 'wind' (n) got shortened in the seventeenth century for some reasons. The short and long vowels in 'child' and 'children' can also be attributed to the same sound change.

## ℎ

By about the tenth century (Late Old English), there was a sound change called **Homorganic Lengthening (HL)** through which original short vowels were lengthened in certain words in the environment of a following **voiced homorganic cluster**. To be precise, before a cluster of Sonorant (Nasal or Liquid) + voiced homorganic obstruent.

*Homorganic* means having the same place of articulation, so vowels before clusters like /**nd**/, /**ld**/, /**mb**/, /**rd**/, /**rn**/, /**ŋɡ**/ etc., were lengthened in certain words. The change also applied to some clusters with /r/ as their first element such as /rd/, /rn/, /rl/, /rð/ (Donka Minkova) so the vowel in words like *board, hoard, yearn, earl, earth* etc., were also lengthened due to HL.

#### Examples

- A striking example of HL is the word 'climb':
  Old English *climban* and would've been pronounced with a short vowel before HL: /ˈkl**i**m.bɑn/, it became: /ˈkl**iː**m.bɑn/<sup>**1**</sup>
- 'Ground' was OE *grund*, pronounced /ɡr**u**nd/, it became /ɡr**uː**nd/<sup>**2**</sup>
- 'Blind' was OE *blind*, pronounced /bl**i**nd/, it became /bl**iː**nd/
- 'Field' was OE *feld*, pronounced /f**e**ld/, it became /f**eː**ld/<sup>**3**</sup>

### Influence of a third consonant

However, the lengthening didn't take place when the homorganic cluster in question was followed by a third consonant. It means **HC+C** ('HC' being the homorganic cluster and 'C' another consonant) cluster was impervious to HL. This can be illustrated by the following example:

- 'Hound' was OE *hund* and pronounced /x**u**nd/, it became /x**uː**nd/. 'Hundred', on the other hand, was *hundred*, pronounced /ˈxu**ndr**ed/, it didn't change because the homorganic cluster /nd/ was followed by a third consonant /r/.

The vowel in 'grind' is long due to HL and that of 'grindstone' (ModE: /ˈɡraɪn(d)stəʊn/) should've been short because the /nd/ is followed by a third consonant, but it isn't. Otto Jespersen says that 'grindstone' was formerly always /ˈgrinstən/ and the long vowel in ModE is by analogy with 'grind'.

This point also accounts for the long and short vowels in 'child' and 'children'.

#### Child vs children

- 'child' was OE *ċild*, pronounced /t͡ʃ**i**ld/, it became /t͡ʃ**iː**ld/
- 'children' was OE *ċildru*, pronounced /t͡ʃ**i**ldru/, it didn't undergo the sound change because the cluster /ldr/ was impervious to HL.

#### Don't let the w[ɪ]nd w[aɪ]nd you up

There are different assumptions as to why the vowels in 'wind' (v) and 'wind' (n) are different:

- Donka Minkova says 'the pair *wind* - *wind* is a special case, probably best explained on the grounds of homophony avoidance'.
- Jeremy Smith says that this is a sporadic instance of HL where it failed. He goes on to say '[t]his distinction may be the result of a disambiguating choice between variant pronunciations to avoid confusion between two meanings'
- Otto Jespersen says that the noun *wind* used to have /iː/, but it got shortened by analogy with frequent compounds such as *windmill (also [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229181?result=1)), window* which had short vowels.
- [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229181?result=1) and [A History of Modern English sounds and morphology by Eilert Ekwall](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_History_of_Modern_English_Sounds_and_M.html?id=4-46swEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) say that the short vowel is due to analogy with *windy*.

This was a sporadic sound change and only affected certain words. There are many, many words that have a 'voiced homorganic cluster' at the end, yet they have short vowels: *band, hand, land, dumb, lamb, sand, send, held, bend, blend, end, rend, send, spend, wend* etc. (Minkova)

---

### Notes

1. The nasal endings (/ɑn/) were later on lost. The reason 'climb' has /aɪ/ (instead of /iː/) in ModE is because of the GVS.
2. /uː/ to /aʊ/ shift is also because of the GVS.
3. /eː/ to /iː/ shift can also be ascribed to the GVS.

---

#### Abbreviations

- HL: Homorganic Lengthening
- OE: Old English
- ME: Middle English
- ModE: Modern English
- OED: Oxford English Dictionary
- GVS: Great Vowel Shift

#### References

- [A Historical Phonology of English by Donka Minkova](https://edinburghuniversitypress.com/book-a-historical-phonology-of-english.html)
- [Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles by Otto Jespersen](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_Modern_English_Grammar_on_Historical_P.html?id=0CYIsm4MaIkC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)
- [A History of Modern English sounds and morphology by Eilert Ekwall](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/A_History_of_Modern_English_Sounds_and_M.html?id=4-46swEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)
- [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229181?result=1)
- [Sound Change and the History of English by Jeremy Smith](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Sound_Change_and_the_History_of_English.html?id=8bpyNOFDLEMC&redir_esc=y)
- [Old English: A Historical Linguistic Companion by Roger Lass](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/old-english/A477ADDA70E35C8C92F123FAB2C57CCD)

Comment: Curious why you're using serif unicode characters for the "TL;DR" while the site uses sans-serif :)

Comment: "will further explain later" there's more??

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: Yeah. This is only a brief summary :)

Comment: @AndrewT.: Because serif unicode looks better than the (dumb) sans serif :D

Comment: Couldn't have hoped for a better answer

Comment: An excellent answer. Nicely written, Void.

Comment: That's some horrific kerning on "".

Answer (score 2):

They *didn't* both come from the same word. Their entries at [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=wind) show two different sources.

The change in the pronunciation of the noun from long (like 'find') to short (like 'pinned') is comparatively recent. According to Etymonline:

> [wind] shifted to a short vowel 18c., probably from influence of *windy*,
> where the short vowel is natural. A sad loss for poets, who now must
> rhyme it only with sinned and a handful of weak words.

Comment: Indeed. Shakespeare has _Blow, blow, thou winter wind/Thou art not so unkind/As man's ingratitude_, and the carol 'God rest you merry, gentlemen' has _The Shepherds at those tidings/Rejoiced much in mind,/And left their flocks a feeding/In tempest, storm and wind._

Comment: @Void: A hinder? Where'd you get that?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: It was meant to be a joke

Comment: @Void: Oh. Jokes. No. It's 2021: we don't get those any more. Not round Brixton. Kate quoted As You Like It, which is full of hinds and hind-rhymes (like Touchstone mocking Orlando's inept love-poem with his own sexually suggestive one) and I thought you were referencing Shakespeare. It's a cruel disappointment but I'll rise above it.