# How do I decide if an "i" is pronounced long or short?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, vowels, orthography

I am an English teacher who has never really learned the complex rules of teaching pronunciation.  Many learners here in Spain have difficulties deciding whether an "i" in a word is long or short.  Unfortunately, even the basic general rule of "it's a long 'i' if it's a short word with a silent 'e' at the end" doesn't work, as we came across "live" and "give"... and the multisyllable "practice/practise".

I can't seem to find a pattern (*emphatise* vs *expertise*, and *sign* vs *signature* and *signal* came up).

Can anyone point me in the direction of a relatively simple explanation?

Comment: I don't think there is one - you just have to learn the pronunciation of each word, I'm afraid. _Live_ as a verb rhymes with _give_, but as an adjective (as in _live animals_) it rhymes with _drive_.

Comment: A lot of very common words are exceptions to the general rules - like "give", "done", "are", "have" - but this doesn't change the fact that the patterns are there and often a good guide to how to pronounce 90% of monosyllables, and these rules form the basis of how a native speaker will guess the pronunciation - for example, if we've never come across the word "mive" or "gline" or "brile" before (I made these up), we'll give it a long (diphthongised) i. Polysyllablic words are more difficult - I'm sure there are rules and patterns, but less easy to generalise.

Comment: "Expertise" is a relatively recent borrowing from French ("machine" is also from French) so the "i" is /i:/ (which isn't short, but isn't diphthongised either).

Comment: For polysyllables you have to look at both stress patterns ( https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/why-are-finite-and-infinite-pronounced-differently?rq=1 ) and trisyllabic laxing ( https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265605/why-are-south-and-southern-pronounced-with-different-vowels?rq=1 ).  There are some words that can be pronounced either way though ("missile", "tactile" - for these two examples BrE favours the diphthong, AmE the monophthong, but I think there are some words where the preference is the other way round).

Comment: emphatise? Did you mean empathize? Or maybe emphasize?

Answer (score 28):

There isn't a relatively simple explanation, I'm afraid. As you've pointed out, there are more exceptions-to-rules than than there are rules; however, there are some general *guidelines* that might help you:

- #### **before double consonants**

  before double consonants, 'i' is usually short regardless of its position in a word: as in bi**tt**en, hi**dd**en, mi**ff**ed, bi**gg**er, pi**gg**y, ri**bb**on, ni**bb**le, chi**ll**, pi**ll**ow, i**mm**une, si**mm**er, di**nn**er, i**nn**ocent, sni**pp**et, hi**pp**o, i**rr**egular, i**rr**elevant, mi**ss**, bli**ss**, i**ss**ue etc (the only exception I can think of is 'dissect' which can be pronounced either with a short 'i' or long)
- #### in prefixes

  'i' in common prefixes such as *in- (im-, il-, ir-), infra-, inter-, intra-, hemi-, dis-* etc is pronounced short (exc. *bi-* and *di-*)
- #### before the suffix *-tion*

  before the suffix *-tion* (in simple words, ***i**tion* words), it's almost always short as in compet**i**tion, cond**i**tion, inhib**i**tion, exhib**i**tion, recogn**i**tion, trans**i**tion, add**i**tion etc
- #### in *ity* and *ible*

  in *ity* and *ible*, it's usually short (either /ɪ/ or /ə/) as in abil**i**ty, activ**i**ty, elastic**i**ty, sexual**i**ty, vis**i**ble, edible, eligible, tangible, divis**i**ble etc but there may be exceptions
- #### in the suffix *-ise/-ize*

  the 'i' in the suffix *-ise/-ize* is almost always long as in real**i**se, actual**i**se, mesmer**i**se, hypnot**i**se, formal**i**se, italic**i**se, memor**i**se etc. Also, as @rjpond pointed out in a comment: "Expertise" is a relatively recent borrowing from French ("machine" is also from French) so the "i" is /i:/ (which isn't short, but isn't diphthongised either).
- #### in *ic* and *ical* words

  before *ic* and *ical*, 'i' is almost always short as in class**i**c, lunat**i**c, log**i**c, iron**i**c, fanat**i**c, genet**i**c, class**i**cal, histor**i**cal, phys**i**cal, mechan**i**cal,  etc
- #### before digraphs

  a digraph is 'a combination of two letters representing one sound' (Lexico). For example, the *ck* in 'back' or the *ph* in 'physics' or the *ng* in 'ring'. Before consonant digraphs (and consonant trigraphs), 'i' is usually short as in st**i**ck, br**i**ck, r**i**ng, k**i**ng, f**i**sh, lav**i**sh, r**i**dge, br**i**dge r**i**ch, sandw**i**ch, w**i**tch, p**i**tch etc
- #### in *-ing*

  in the inflectional suffix *-ing*, 'i' is almost always short as in mak**i**ng, rain**i**ng, kill**i**ng, sell**i**ng, feel**i**ng, hid**i**ng, water**i**ng, hitt**i**ng, sitt**i**ng, call**i**ng etc
- #### words ending in *ign*

  words ending in *ign* usually have the long 'i' sound as in s**i**gn, cons**i**gn, mal**i**gn, des**i**gn, res**i**gn, al**i**gn, ass**i**gn, ben**i**gn etc.
- #### before *gh* words

  before *gh*, 'i' is usually pronounced long 'i' as in s**i**ght, f**i**ght, m**i**ght, h**i**gh, s**i**gh, he**i**ght, sl**i**ght, n**i**ght, br**i**ght, r**i**ght etc (ex. 'weight' which is pronounced with /eɪ/)
- #### before *nd* and *ld*

  before *nd* and *ld*, 'i' is sometimes long as in w**i**nd (v.), k**i**nd, bl**i**nd, m**i**nd, m**i**ld, ch**i**ld, f**i**nd etc (for *w[ɪ]nd* vs *w[aɪ]nd*, read [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272179/106592))
- #### before silent *e*

  words ending in **iCe** ('i' being letter 'i', 'C' another consonant, 'e' the silent e) are usually, not always, pronounced with a long 'i' as in hide, site, kite, white, wife, oblige, like, spike, bike, file, tile, while, time, prime, line, fine, pipe, gripe, size etc. **Exceptions:** recipe, clandestine, astatine and routine (long 'e': /iː/), urine (can also be pronounced with long 'i'), iodine (it can also be pronounced with long i), ive-words below etc
- #### words ending in *ive*

  *ive* words are tricky. Most words having the prefix *-ive* have short 'i': relative, conservative, fricative, figurative, active, argumentative etc. By contrast, live (adj), dive, drive, five, revive, alive etc are pronounced with a long 'i'
- #### CiC words

  words in which 'i' is flanked by two other consonants is usually pronounced short as in signal, signature, sit, fit, kit, hit, lit, spit etc (ex. *title, vital*)

There are also other exceptions such as:

- [*f**i**nite - inf**i**nite, m**i**grant - imm**i**grant*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/259576/106592), [*divine - divinity*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265606/106592)
- It's pronunciation varies when it occurs in combination with another vowel.
- Before rC (r + another consonant) it's usually /ɜː/ in British English and /ɝ/ in American English: *bird, skirt, shirt, dirt, firm, irk, quirk* etc

There are no hard and fast rules. Sorry.

---

(Long 'i' is /aɪ/ as in *bite*, short 'i' is /ɪ/ as in *bit*.)

Comment: That looks like a pretty comprehensive list! Not that I'd have any idea if you missed out a few fairly common cases. Did you put it together yourself, or find it in some reference work?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I did it all by myself except for the ‘before *gh*’; I got that idea from somewhere I don't remember now. There are many more guidelines such as [TSL (divine - divinity group)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265605/why-are-south-and-southern-pronounced-with-different-vowels?rq=1) and [**stress** (finite - infinite)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/why-are-finite-and-infinite-pronounced-differently?rq=1) (rjpond's comment) etc., but it would further confuse the OP.

Comment: Well, it certainly looks like an excellent "reference page" to me! I've been on this site for over 8 years now, and this is only the 12th post that seems worth me "bookmarking" it (within the site UI, not my browser) in case I might want to redirect future related queries here.

Comment: Of possible note, the double consonant rule actually applies to other vowels as well as ‘i’ (though the exact change it induces is not always consistent). It’s one of a handful of easy to point out aspects of English’s Germanic heritage. Most other Germanic languages also signal ‘shortening’ of a the preceding vowel with a doubled consonant.

Comment: Good list! I was trying to think of any odd-ones-out for "ic" — only one that comes to mind is "chic", but again it's a modern-ish loan word.

Comment: An outstanding answer. Must represent a LOT of work.

Comment: "'i' in common prefixes such as in- (im-, il-, ir-), infra-, inter-, intra-, hemi-, dis- etc is pronounced short" "hemi-" and "demi-" are both pronounced with long vowels, though, with either the vowels of "bee" or "eye", depending on the word (e.g. "demigod" is "dem-eye-god", and "hemisphere" is "hem-ee-sfere" if you don't contract the vowel into a schwa).

Comment: Also, I don't think that "-ing" is a short "i" sound unless you contract it to "-in'"; it's also an "ee" sound like "bee", and you can tell because "being" has the same sound twice in a row.

Comment: "clandestine" rhymes with "urine" - I have heard the `i` pronounced long by some speakers.

Comment: One explanation for the two pronounciatons of _dissect_ is that its etymology is _di-_ + _sect_ (suggesting long), but the double _s_ spelling (or possible back-formation of _dis-_) leads speakers to the short vowel.

Comment: @nick012000: Good points! though I think it depends on dialect for example all those words you mentioned have a short vowel for me and Lexico agrees. 'ing' definitely has a short vowel; 'being' is phonemically /ˈbiːɪŋ/ which can be analysed as /ˈbiː/ +/ɪŋ/ (short vowel)

Comment: @Void Yes, I've only ever heard "hemi" and "demi" with monophthongal vowels in BrE.  "Multi" is another that always has a monophthong in BrE, but often a diphthong /aɪ/ in AmE.

Comment: @nick012000 short/long isn't a strict dichotomy, there's actually a spectrum of pronunciations, and it can be difficult to label the sounds in the middle. And accents also add variation.

Answer (score 0):

Grammar is music theory for language.  Music doesn't sound good because it follows music theory, music theory is written about music that sounds good.  There is no such thing as a "rule" for language, because languages are highly specific in unpredictable ways.  Languages have evolved by people making sounds at each other until telepathy was achieved, because the language centres of our brains are hardwired to be able to generate and understand human languages.  You can't write that down as "rules".  Even if you could, none would ever be short enough to recall with the subconscious instancy required for native speed speech.

Teaching someone a formula for language will not help them acquire that language.  I never learnt the grammar "rule" behind why one of the two phrases "the green big tree" and "the big green tree" is incorrect, I can just *feel* it.  I know instantly by looking at them, and can't force myself to think otherwise.

The way for your students to acquire whether it's a short or long I is the exact same way they'll acquire anything else - comprehensible input.  They need to listen to native level speakers more, and pay active attention to the things about which they're confused.

On a note more specific to this exact example, how a word is pronounced is based on accent.  Think of the different ways a hillbilly and an East Londoner would pronounce "hill".

Comment: 'There is no such thing as a "rule" for language, because languages are highly specific in unpredictable ways' – Most languages that are written with an alphabet have strict pronunciation rules, and knowing the spelling allows you to determine the pronunciation something like 99% of the time. English is unusual (and perhaps unique) in being an alphabetic language that has only a vague correspondence between spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: It's also well-established that when people are learning to read, it is much better to teach them explicit rules about how characters are pronounced than to merely provide them large amounts of comprehensible input. But I admit that in *this* case (how to pronounce the English letter I), studying and memorizing lots and lots of rules may not be an efficient way to learn.

Comment: "Most languages that are written with an alphabet have strict pronunciation rules" the portion you quoted was about language as a whole, not just spelling.  Also you're conflating learning with acquiring.  You can learn that a "dog" is a four legged animal with fur that barks, but that's not going to help you understand a spoken sentence about a dog.  When you acquire language, you can't NOT understand it, it becomes meaning before you even listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

The spelling patterns of words can indicate to us whether a word is more likely to be pronounced /ɪ/ or /iː/, as listed by @Toby Speight above.

Some students can learn by memorising rules and to others it will make no difference. For students like this, they will need to actively practice /iː/ and /ɪ/ words separately in sentences. This will eventually build the capacity of your ear and tongue to tell the difference. The goal is to get used to the difference so that you intuitively know it.

It's the only way that works for students who can't remember or apply rules. I have made two audio practise lessons on this topic:

Learn /iː/ lesson: https://jadejoddle.com/english-accent-practice/

Learn /ɪ/ lesson: https://jadejoddle.com/english-accent-practice-audio/