# How to explain "ind" pronunciation to your son?

Tags: pronunciation

Find is /fʌɪnd/ rather than /fɪnd/.My son is six He asked where is the silent e- How I explain its pronunciation? All inds are like that so making it a sight word is a bit burdensome.

Answer (score 1):

The idiosyncrasy here is historical. In Late Old English, there was a sound change called [Homorganic Lengthening](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272179/106592) which lengthened the short vowel when it was followed by consonant clusters like /nd/, /ld/, /rd/, /mb/ etc.

Almost all the words ending in *-ind* (and *-ild*) are pronounced with the 'long i' sound (/aɪ/) for example *mind, kind, find, wind (v), mild, child* etc., except [*wind*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272179/106592) (n). The exceptions are very few and can be learnt by rote, so it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Not the explanation for a six year old.

Comment: @user2617804: You could tell your six yo to pronounce all the *-ind* words with the long i except *wind* (=breeze). :)

Comment: @user2617804 the explanation for a six year old is that English spelling has so many rules that almost no one knows them all, so sometimes you just have to memorize that one word sounds one way and another sounds another way, even though they are spelled similarly (or identically as in the case of wind (breeze) and wind (twist))

Comment: What I am looking for in online content covering this particular case?

Comment: @user2617804: Sorry?

Comment: How do kid's teachers explain the anomalous pronunciation of ind words?

Comment: @user2617804: I'm not a teacher so I don't know, but usually children learn the pronunciation of every word by rote. English spelling is ridiculous and not a good way to teach pronunciation